# Имеет ли смысл переходить на Java при наличии немалого опыта в php,js?

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток, прекрасно понимаю что однозначного ответа на этот вопрос нет и что все-равно решать мне, просто так сложилось что я уже достиг определенного уровня в php, js при этом я чисто на досуге все это время учил java (очень нравится язык и "навязаное ооп")

Ну собственно суть в следующем - имеет ли смысл поднажать в сторону java и пытаться искать работу уже java разработчика, или все-таки лучше так и писать на php и js?
Очень интересуют вообще какие требования к java-junior программистам (не в гугле а по факту)

Основная причина этого стремления - начинаю терять интерес к php и js, но на данный момент это мой хлеб
 Вообщем очень жду ваших ответов и вообще реально ли, уже обладая базовыми знаниями java и знаниями php,js скажем за месяц подтянуться по java до уровня junior?
Интересует личный опыт и вообще любый ваши мысли по этому поводу, заранее благодарен...
*PS:речь идет именно о быстром переходе, о том что когда-то я и так буду знать java я вурсе...*

Comment: поищите на сайте вопросы нивичков а-ля "java с чего начать" там уже разписали требования к java программеру. junior отличается лиш тем что любой его шаг должен контролировать более опытный колега.

имхо быстрый переход вам сейчас ничего не даст. активно изучая java вы потеряете в основной своей квалификации и скорее за все в финансах тоже. 

пожалуй более надежно было бы поучаствовать в проэкте где серверную часть пишут более-менне опытные люди. как вариант: разбирайтесь исходном коде open source продуктов

Comment: стоит добавить что java в чистом виде сейчас мало востребована. поэтому сразу надо учить 10-30 разных сопутствующих технологий (юзать поиск по сайту). web-девелопмент для вас не чужд, поищите информацию о фреймворках для веб. пробуйте писать сначала программы на php, потом на java+framework

Comment: Не стоит смотреть на код open source продуктов, так как код там в 99% является полным г*****.

Comment: тут стоит уточнить я имел в виду не любых open source а более-менее известных и признаных (e.g. apache, etc...), тем более что декпомпилировать класссы не является проблемой.

Comment: про яву в чистом виде - уверен на 100% что тут так-же как и в php,js...<br>
Зная нормально язык любая библиотека фреймворк и т.д. изучаются в кратчайшие сроки, ява мне интересна в первую очередь как сервер и для написания ПО под Android...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы хороший PHP-разработчик, то от перехода на Java вы только выиграете. Со временем и в деньгах тоже. Однако, мгновенный переход маловероятен. Как уже говорил 1101й, поначалу будет получаться плохой код и потребуется время, чтобы победить его как снаружи (исправить баги), так и внутри (поправить мышление определённым образом).

Comment: Спасибо большое за ваш совет, значит будем как и раньше стараться выделять время на изучение java...

Answer (score 3):

*Мысли ни о чем*

Если есть желание, то в любом случае стоит перейти, ну или хотя бы попробовать :)

Если долго сидеть на одном языке, то мозги подсохнут, и дальше изучать что-то новое будет уже тяжелее.

Уверен что поначалу будете писать плохой код на яве, не потому что вы плохой программист, а потому что просто не знаете всех плюх новой технологии, к тому же на яве можно писать не только серверные вещи, но и многое-многое другое, так что дерзайте, и удачи вам в этом благом начинании.

Comment: Я вкурсе что на java можно писать не только "серверные вещи", насчет плюх вы скорее всего ошибаетесь т.к. если я учу java на досуге это не значит что я не знаю плюх :)<br>
Желание есть, интересует поиск работы и реально ли асилить необходимый минимум junior за месяц...<br>
В любом случае и на этом спасибо :)

Comment: Поиск работы зависит не только от вашей квалификации, но и еще от наличия вакансий :)

Асилить можно все что угодно, только у кого-то на одну вещь уходит неделя, а у кого-то месяц...

Если вы знаете все плюхи Java, то вы наверно уже не джуниор ;-)

Comment: Я не писал что знаю все, но о том что вообще можно творить в java коде знаю неплохо :)